# How to display the html i tag inside a button using php Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i am trying to produce this using code igniter php

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-bricky pull-right ">
   Login 
   <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
</button>
```

i have done this in my login_view.php

```
<?php
    $data = array(
                   'class' => 'btn btn-bricky pull-right fa fa-arrow-circle-right',
                   'type' => 'submit',
                   'content' => 'Login'
                );
    echo form_button($data); 
 ?>
```

but it doesn't produce the desired result. How can i do that using codeigniter helper functions?. This is purely styling related goal that i want to achieve using codeigniter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the problem is you're giving the button itself the fa classes which place the icon before the element that has the class. Give this a shot (not sure if it will work, completely untested)

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        'class' => 'btn btn-bricky pull-right',
        'type' => 'submit',
        'content' => 'Login<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>'
    );
    echo form_button($data);
?>
```